# Java Subclasses General Concept

Tags: java, subclass

For fun, I am wanting to make a basketball simulation game in Java. I am wanting to have one simple class "team" and I want to have a subclass of class team named "player".  I understand how to declare classes and subclasses but my question is how do I declare a player to a certain team?

For example:

```
Team team1 = new Team();
Team team2 = new Team();
Player nameHere = new Player();
```

How do I set it to where Player nameHere is on team1, or team2, etc...

Comment: That's called association. Looks like `Team` needs a `List<Player>` field and `Player` needs a `Team` field.

Comment: A player is an entirely different entity than a Team, don't make it a subclass.

Comment: What does your Team and Player code look like?  Please post more details regarding what you've written.

Answer (score 2):

There are two important software design principles you need to understand:

```
- Inheritance (IS A relationship)

- Composition (HAS A relationship)
```

When you deal with the first concept, you use classes and subclasses. But in this case, your subclass is essentially the same as your parent class: it is like a car and Ferrari. Ferrari **IS A** car (this kind of relationship is represented by inheritance in OOP). 
Nevertheless, a car **HAS A** wind screen. Wind screen is not a car, it is its part (this relationship is represented by the inclusion of one class as a field member of another class - composition). 
Now, that you know about these relationships, you need to ask yourself a question: **IS** Player **A** team, or **HAS** team **A** Player?

In this case, it seems obvious. You need to place a `List<Player>` inside your `Team` class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you fully understand what Inherritance means.
A subclass of a superclass should be a special case of the superclass.

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html for more examples.

What you want is a class team with an attrute

```
List<Player> players;
```

I suggest you read up on inherritance if you want to write any object-oriented code.

Answer (score 1):

Others have offered great explanations, but let me add something.

A lot of inexperienced developers use subclassing to save code. They are so enamored with the inheritance they learned in school that they are anxious to factor everything out to some common base class and subclass it like crazy.

That is the wrong approach.

A class should subclass another class not if they share code but if they share the same *behavior*. So ask yourself, does a player have the same behavior as a team?

Probably not.

A team, for example, has a schedule, a list of opponents, an owner, a city, an attendance figure, a stadium, and so on. Players do not. So `Player` should not subclass `Team`. A `Team`, however, makes sense to be composed of a `List<Player>` as others have mentioned.

But let's make this more complicated and interesting now.

Let's consider a soccer team. A player on the team can have goals, assists, and fouls. The team could also have all those things, where the team's value for those things is the sum of those values for all the players. But rather than use inheritance, you would be better served using an *interface* called something like `Measurable` (lame name, I know) and have both `Team` and `Player` implement that interface. Let's say `Measurable` has a `getGoals()` method. Then if the client says

```
int goals = measurable.getGoals();
```

the client doesn't know or care if he is getting the number of goals for a team or a player--just that the object knows how many goals it has.

This in fact is an example of the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

So the bottom line is that `Player` should not sublcass `Team`, but `Team` should be composed of `Player` because they have different behaviors. But if they do have common attributes like name, goals, etc., then use an interface to represent that as a common way to describe entirely different kinds of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
class Player {

//player properties and setter , getter

}

class Team{

  List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

  // setter and getter  
}
```

Adding Player to the Team

```
Team t1= new Team();

Player p1 = new Player(); 
Player p2 = new Player();
Player p3 = new Player();

t1.getPlayers().add(p1);
t1.getPlayers().add(p2);
t1.getPlayers().add(p3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something similar to this.

```
class Team {
    List<Player> players;

    Team() {
        players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player p) {
        players.add(p);
    }
}
```

And this is how you create and add `Player` to `Team`:

```
Player player1 = new Player();
Player player2 = new Player();
Team team1 = new Team();
team1.addPlayer(player1);
team1.addPlayer(player2);
```

Thing to know is `inheritance (is a)` vs `composition(has a)` relationships.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of your `Team` as a container for `Player`s, your `Team` class will have a property that contains the `Player`s, and accessor methods to add, remove, clear, etc. the `Team`'s players.

Of course, your `Team` class will have its own properties and methods, possibly tapping data  from whatever `Player`s you have in the team (e.g. the number of players, etc.).

In this instance **there is no topic related to inheritance**.

Your classes just have a container vs "containee" relationship (Artem's answer uses the proper terminology).

For instance:

```
class Team {
    // the private property containing the players
    // I use a Set here because each player is unique
    private Set<Player> players;
    public Team() {
        // initializing the set as HashSet
        players = new HashSet<Player>();
    }
    public void addPlayers(Player... players) {
        // adding all players
        for (Player p: players) {
            this.players.add(p);
        }
    }
    public Collection<Player> getPlayers() {
        // returning a copy of the team's players
        return new HashSet<Player>(players);
    }
}
class Player {
    // TODO player's properties such as name, age, feats, etc.
}
```

Then you'd add `Player`s to your `Team` as such:

```
Team t = new Team();
// adding single player
t.addPlayers(new Player());
// adding an array of players
t.addPlayers(new Player[]{new Player(), new Player()});
```